# Google map, disable Dragging/Panning by mouse

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-maps, draggable, panning

I know in Java `googleMap.draggable = false;` in "*google.maps.MapOptions* object specification" disables dragging, but how it works for Action Script 3.0 ? I want to disable dragging/panning by mouse. I used `googleMap.disableDragging();` but it doesn`t work ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this little (I think working) sample: http://www.stupidiocy.com/development/using-the-google-maps-api-with-as3/ (it uses `disableDragging` on a `Map` object).